# Is there a way to define 26mV thermal voltage with simple words

Tags: voltage, thermal

This 26mV thermal voltage at room temperature is used in non-linear diode equation.
I tried to learn about it to see what it means without getting involved in too much physics but failed to find a simple explanation.

Is there a way to describe it without involving in too much theory and background?

Is this just a number that fits the empirical results like a constant?

Comment: Huh? What? You mention a particular thermal voltage but neglect to define it or provide any context.

Comment: is this for a school assignment?

Comment: I'd recommend not worrying too much. It's not even accurate in all situations (where quantum effects become important.) But also look up the equipartition rule. See if that makes sense. It's based on that concept. Either way, just think of it as something that "arises out of large-number population statistics" and doesn't really exist at the fine level of the atom or below.

Comment: Imho is pretty clear what the question is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intuitively, it is the mean potential caused by the thermal motion of electrons.

It is

\$ \displaystyle V_T=\frac{kT}{q}\$

where T is the absolute temperature, k is the Boltzman constant and q is the charge on an electron.

---

If you would like to think of the cloud of electrons as a gas it is also

\$\displaystyle V_T=\frac{RT}{F}\$

where T is the absolute temperature, R is the [gas constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant) (which relates energy to temperature) and F is the [Faraday constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_constant) (charge per mole of electrons).

Comment: Or remember that \$k=\frac{R}{N_\text{A}}\$. (Avagadro's constant is taught in high school because it is as simple as the idea of counting things.) Of course, someone defined a constant for that particular bucket of electrons, \$q\cdot N_\text{A}\$, and gave it a name we can forget about.

Answer (score 3):

I always think it is better to talk in terms of about thermal energy than thermal voltage.

I open up Bart whenever I have to remember how we walk the walk from solid state to I-V curves: https://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter1/ch1_4.htm

Quoting:

> Finally, we need to introduce the thermal voltage, Vt, the potential
>   an electron needs to traverse to gain an energy equal to the thermal
>   energy kT. This voltage equals the thermal energy divided by the
>   electronic charge, q, of the electron:
>   $$V_t = \frac{kT}{q}$$
>   The numeric value of thermal voltage in Volt also equals the thermal energy in units of electron-Volt. At 300K (27oC) Vt equals 25.86 mV.

Whereas the thermal energy relates an energy to an occupancy probability directly through the Boltzmann distribution, which comes with the exponential and whatnot.

$$ \propto \exp \left( \Delta E / k_B T\right)$$

Bart states that the thermal voltage is just the potential in which an electron would increase its energy by the thermal energy \$ k_BT \$ when it traverses through.

It is not evident to me that it carries an extra insight than this. Sometimes they do, sometimes they don't. (:

Comment: I must add that it is sometimes not relevant **not** to use equations when one talks about a phenomenon or a concept.  Unlike engineering, nature is not present to be understood, and often unintuitive colloquially. Equations **are** the language that facilitates intuition.

Comment: Regarding "Bart", the link target is gone. :-(

Answer (score 1):

When we talk about semiconductors, there exists **thermal voltage** which ranges from 25 to 26 mV as you mentioned. I'm no chemist but it comes from the [Boltzmann Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant) that is arbitrarily noted as \$k\$.

We use \$k\$ for a lot of things including the Ideal Gas Law in chemistry or thermodynamics, etc. It relates to the kinetic energy of the particles in gas state of matter.

Consider this equation: \$k=R/N_A\$ where \$R\$ is a gas constant that is related to the [molar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant) with ideal gases and \$N_A\$ is simply [Avogardro's Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant).

In Shockley Diode Equation, thermal voltage is equal to \$ \displaystyle V_T=\frac{kT}{q}\$ where \$T\$ is an ambient temperature and \$q\$ is the charge of an electron. At 300 Kelvin, thermal voltage is \$\approx\$25.85 mV... and that's pretty much it...

It's a relationship between electrostatic potential and electric current across a P-N junction. You can utilize the calculation of the thermal voltage when you model a diode.

Comment: you wrote many equations. Between which points is the thermal voltage occurs?

Comment: Reread my answer :) Second to last sentence: `It's a relationship between...` If you took a multimeter and (somehow) measured between the P-N junction in a diode, it will give your thermal voltage assuming that you don't have anything else connected to the diode.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to do some more research before you post a question.

A web search for `26mV thermal voltage` led to `thermal voltage equation`.

That resulted in this.

**posted by Jose21**

> **Thermal Voltage**
>
> At 0 K, electrons in a semiconductor are in rest..or you can say 0
>   energy state. As we increase the temperature, electron starts getting
>   energy proportional to the temperature and this constant of
>   proportionality is k, the Boltzmann constant. kT/q is the voltage
>   corresponding to this energy. Since the cause of this voltage is
>   temperature, it is so called Thermal Voltage. It is an average value.
>   For individual electrons, it can vary a little, but on an average, it
>   will be kT/q. At a given temperature, an electron can have energies as
>   multiples of kT.

Reference https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/what-is-thermal-voltage.589409/

Comment: But voltage is measured between two terminals. Between which points is the thermal voltage occurs? I cannot picture this in my mind.

Comment: The text answers that. 0 potential == energy at 0K. Simple as that.

Comment: `Between which points is the thermal voltage occurs?` .... I do not understand it completely. ... I posted what appeared to be a reasonable statement based on all my knowledge. .... I think that the `thermal voltage` is equivalent to `heat` when referring to gases. Which means that `thermal voltage` is the energy with which electrons move around when not subjected to external forces. .... So, I think that the Thermal Voltage manifests itself across a P-N junction, where you have excess electrons on one side of the P-N junction, and a lack of electrons on the other side of the P-N junction.